# Explicit simd code in D

Tags: d, simd, avx

Is it possible to do it now in D out of the box ? I'm using LDC2 compiler if it can help.
I'm interested using AVX intrinsics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment DMD has no AVX intrinsics. Considering that all D compilers use the DMD frontend, and the druntime and phobos, I would say that the only way to do what you want is to use the in-line assembly as suggested by BCS.

I would advise you to check from time to time the `core.simd` module and see if AVX intrinsics are added.

Answer (score 1):

There is inline ASM. I think DMD supports the SIMD instructions. Not sure what the story for LDC is.

Comment: Inline ASM is totally impracticable because of register allocation by hand.

Comment: If you don't want asm, then what are you wanting for 'explicit'? Something that's assured to use them? I assume you've checked the intrinsics list? All that's left is the compiler  promising to use them on array operations.

Comment: By explicit I mean using intrinsics like `_mm256_load_ps` and declaring `__m256` variables, etc as you do with gcc or clang. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

With LDC, module `ldc.gccbuiltins_x86` contains GCC-style builtins like `__builtin_ia32_vfnmaddps256`.

(there is also `ldc.gccbuiltins_arm`, and `ldc.gccbuiltins_ppc`, ...)